# ansible nested loop over a single dict

Tags: list, loops, dictionary, ansible

I've got a list of dict like:

```
- { "a": "zzz", "b": [1, 2] }
- { "a": "yyy", "b": [7, 9] }
```

I need with ansible to loop over it so item would be successively:

```
- { "a": "zzz", "b": 1 }
- { "a": "zzz", "b": 2 }
- { "a": "yyy", "b": 7 }
- { "a": "yyy", "b": 9 }
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it can be done in 1 task, but here is how i would do it:

You need 1 loop for the "master" list and then 1 dynamic loop for the list of the 'b' key. We will use an `include_tasks` task in order to process each dict of the "master" list, then in the included tasks file just a `set_fact` to loop the "b" key, and populate our variable.

CODE:

`main.yml`:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    source_var:
    - { "a": "zzz", "b": [1, 2] }
    - { "a": "yyy", "b": [7, 9] }

  tasks:

  - name: print var
    include_tasks: "set_fact.yml"
    with_items: "{{ source_var }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: itemoflist

  - name: print var
    debug:
      var: target_var
```

included PB, called `set_fact.yml`:

```
- name: populate_var
  set_fact:
    target_var: "{{ target_var | default([]) + [{ 'a': itemoflist.a, 'b': item }] }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ itemoflist['b'] }}"
```

variable created:

```
TASK [print var] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "target_var": [
        {
            "a": "zzz",
            "b": 1
        },
        {
            "a": "zzz",
            "b": 2
        },
        {
            "a": "yyy",
            "b": 7
        },
        {
            "a": "yyy",
            "b": 9
        }
    ]
}
```

hope it helps.